# human attribute name in a partial for a form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a shared partial that I'm using in various form_for tags like so:

```
<%= render 'shared/text_field_attribute', :f => f, :attribute => :some_attr, :predicate => 'is/starts with/ends with/etc.' %>
```

app/views/shared/text_field_attribute.html.erb looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label attribute, "#{attribute} #{predicate}", class: 'sr-only' %>
  <%= f.text_field attribute, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "#{f.object.class.human_attribute_name(attribute)} #{predicate}…" %>
</div>
```

Is there anything more concise than this to get the human attribute name?

```
f.object.class.human_attribute_name(attribute)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
f.object.class.human_attribute_name(attribute)
```

You can use [`humanize`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/humanize) method like so:

```
attribute.to_s.humanize
```

Answer (score 0):

If as you said, you are using it in various form_for, I suggest to create an helper (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html).

In the helper you can choose: put in only **text_field** , or both **label** and **text_field**.